# Execution of for loop for flask template rendering

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, flask

I want to return my render template after finished the execution of for loop to get all the Twitter data. But it just returns the 1st tweet in the content. but I want to get all the tweets and return them. How can I do?

```
def myTweets():
     user_name ="elonmusk"
     myPosts=api.user_timeline(screen_name=user_name)
     tweetList=[]
     for tweet in myPosts:
             language = tweet.lang
             twt =tweet.full_text 
             if (language == "en"):
                   engTweets = twt 
                   tweetList.append(twt)
                   tweetCount = len(tweetList)
                       
                   return render_template('tweetCount.html', 
                                     tweetCount=tweetCount)    
             else:
                   return render_template('index.html')
     return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: You have return statements without a function definition. Please show your full code. Also, you never append to tweetList but always return single strings. Makes sense that you only get the first tweet.

Comment: You are not presenting the code that is giving you the problem. The indentation is wrong and there is a syntax error at `else`.

Comment: I updated the code. if relevant Twitter account has 10 tweets, it should be 10 for tweet count. but just return the 1 for every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement stops method's execution where it is reached and returns the value.

Maybe try implementing it as a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) instead of a regular function.